# How do you return an array from a method in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, methods, return

```
private static int findLowestMark(int grade[], int lowestMark []){ 
       int holdingVariable;
       boolean sorted = false;

       while (sorted == false){
           sorted = true;
            for ( int i = 0; i < grade.length-1; i++){
               if ( grade[i] < grade[i+1]){
                   holdingVariable = grade[i+1];
                   grade[i+1] = grade [i];
                   grade[i] = holdingVariable;
                   sorted = false;
               }
            }
       }

       for (int number : grade){
           System.out.println("The sorted values are" + number); 
       }
       return grade[i];
    }
```

Hi guys,

Was hoping one of you could help me this this here, I think I've been looking at it too long and I can't figure out how to solve it.

Basically all I'm trying to do is return grade[i]. However when I'm trying to do this I'm getting the;

can't find symbol variable i compile time error.

Now I know this is because I have initialised and declared i inside the for loop so it can't be used outside the loop.

I then thought of changing the for loop to a while loop and declaring i outside of the loops like this:

```
int i = 0; // altered here
while (sorted == false){
    sorted = true;
     while (i < grade.length-1){ //altered here
          i++;                    // altered here
          if ( grade[i] < grade[i+1]){
               holdingVariable = grade[i+1];
               grade[i+1] = grade [i];
               grade[i] = holdingVariable;
               sorted = false;
          }
    }
}
```

It seemed to work but when I ran the program the sort algorithm wasn't sorting my the numbers in order anymore.

Also we are not allowed to use any import libraries apart from the scanner.

I'm still fairly new to programming, maybe 2 months now so if you could explain things in layman's terms where necessary that would be great lol.

Thanks

Comment: You can find the lowest mark without ordering the array.

Comment: Your method shouldn't do two things at the time (finding the lowest mark and ordering the array/returning it). Use two methods to do these two things.

Comment: your question title is misleading - your problem is simply that `i` is out of scope by the time you call `return grade[i]`.

Comment: @FlorentBayle can't agree more - a method called "findLowestMark" shouldn't mutate the passed array.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you want - in your question you state that you want to return an array from a method, but in your explanation you want to return an element from the array. Could you clarify?

Comment: It is `i` that is undefined, since `i` is only defined within the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Don't return anything. In java *References to objects are passed by value*. The changes made to array  here will be reflected in other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Just return the last value of the sorted array:

```
   private static int findLowestMark(int grade[], int lowestMark []){ 

   int holdingVariable;
   boolean sorted = false;


   while (sorted == false){
       sorted = true;
        for (int i = 0; ; i < grade.length-1; i++){

           if ( grade[i] < grade[i+1]){
               holdingVariable = grade[i+1];
               grade[i+1] = grade [i];
               grade[i] = holdingVariable;
               sorted = false;
           }

        }
   }


   for (int number : grade){
       System.out.println("The sorted values are" + number); 
   }
   return grade[grade.length-1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int[] findLowestMark(int grade[], int lowestMark []){ 
   int holdingVariable;
   boolean sorted = false;

   while (sorted == false){
       sorted = true;
        for ( int i = 0; i < grade.length-1; i++){
           if ( grade[i] < grade[i+1]){
               holdingVariable = grade[i+1];
               grade[i+1] = grade [i];
               grade[i] = holdingVariable;
               sorted = false;
           }
        }
   }

   for (int number : grade){
       System.out.println("The sorted values are" + number); 
   }
   return grade;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the "i++" to the end of while loop?
In the for loop, the "i++" will execute after code in the loop.